# ASP.NET Html Extension not firing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

I have a couple of Extension classes, borrowed from various places, and they both work - individually.  When I try to use both on the same page it appears one does not work.  Here is the setup:

- MVC 2 (no path for upgrading it to MVC 3 or 4)
- HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
- FileBoxHtmlHelperExtension -
  http://forums.asp.net/p/1566760/4033836.aspx

The .ascx page code looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PB.WMATA.ApplicationServices.ViewModels.Files.CIPDocumentAndFile>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Company.Web.Extensions"%>

<div class="editorRow">
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("docs")) { %>

        <%= Html.Hidden("CIPDocument.Id", (Model != null) ? Model.Id : 0) %>

        <label for="CIPNumber">Document Name:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("CIPNumber", (Model != null) ? Model.CIPNumber : "", new { @size = "50", @maxlength = "255" })%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CIPNumber")%>
        &nbsp;
        <% if (Model != null && Model.FileName != null && Model.FileName.Length > 0) { %>
            <label>Current File:</label>
            <%= Model.FileName %>
        <% } else { %>
            <label>
                File Upload:
                    <%= Html.FileBoxFor(m => m.HttpPostedFileBase) %>
            </label>
        <% } %>
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

The output for this looks like:

```
<div class="editorRow">
<input name="docs.index" autocomplete="off" value="1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516" type="hidden">
<input id="docs_1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516__CIPDocument_Id" name="docs[1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516].CIPDocument.Id" value="0" type="hidden">
<label for="CIPNumber">
Document Name:
</label>
<input id="docs_1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516__CIPNumber" maxlength="255" name="docs[1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516].CIPNumber" size="50" value="" type="text">
&nbsp; 
<label>
File Upload: 
<input id="HttpPostedFileBase" name="HttpPostedFileBase" type="file">
</label>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">
delete
</a>
</div>
```

Notice the FileUpload control did not get the HtmlPrefixScope.  I expected it to be:

```
<input id="docs_1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516__HttpPostedFileBase" name="docs[1809201d-2143-4da3-ba34-e443a332c516].HttpPostedFileBase" type="file">
```

I am not quite savvy enough with extensions to see what may be going on.  I suspect that the collection extension is being handled before it tries to handle the filebox extension.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in it turns out that I needed to get at the TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix value as the Html.BeginCollectionItem("docs") call had altered it.  Was really simple once I understood the lifecycle of the TemplateInfo object.  Here is the altered code for the FileBox & FileBoxFor code pieces:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FileBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IDictionary<String, Object> htmlAttributes)
{
    // If the HtmlFieldPrefix has been altered (see HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions class!!) then this will work with it...
    var htmlFieldPrefix = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    name = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlFieldPrefix) ? string.Format("{0}.", htmlFieldPrefix) : "") + name;


    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "file", true);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name, true);
    tagBuilder.GenerateId(name);


    ModelState modelState;
    if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(name, out modelState))
    {
        if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
        }
    }


    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```